# jQuery validation not working when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Ok so I want to use jQuery validation plugin to validate a multi part form, one page at a time.  I'm pretty sure I have most of the script correct but for some reason the below script will not work when originally called through a validateStep function.  The weird thing is that once the validateStep function has been called and the user attempts to enter invalid data the validation works.  its almost like it just turns on the validation on when called but doesn't catch any errors at first. Any ideas why errors are not cough when being called?

Heres my code:

```
function validateStep(step){
    if(step == fieldsetCount) return;


$('#formElem').validate({

    rules: {
       Remail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
       Remail: {
        required: 'We need your email address to contact you',
        email: 'not right'
        }
    }

 }).element($('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')'));

});
```

Comment: _its almost like it just turns on the validation on when called_ -- that's exactly what `.validate()` does. It just enables validation and specifies the options, automatic validation takes place when the user tries to submit the form. If you want to test whether a form is valid, you should call `.valid()`.

Comment: That makes way more sense now...lol  So I use validate to set up the basic rules and then use `.valid().element($('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')'));` to check for errors.  I did this and now I receive the following error from my browser:  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'element'

Comment: `.valid()` just returns `true` or `false`, so you can't chain `.element()` to it. You can apply it to a specific element instead of the whole form.

Comment: `.element()` validates a single element, so actually that should work the way you originally wrote it. You're not using the return value, though -- it should be inside an `if()` statement.

Comment: Or you should set a variable to the validator that `.validate()` returns. See the example at http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Comment: I think I'm on the same track as you.  Writing it this way `if(.valid().element($('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')'))){
      alert("is valid");
     };` seems to be incorrect syntax.  am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var validator = $("#formElem").validate({
    rules: {
       Remail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
       Remail: {
        required: 'We need your email address to contact you',
        email: 'not right'
        }
    }

 });
if (validator.element("#formElem > :nth-child("+parseInt(step)+")")) {
    alert ("is valid");
}
```